# Fastlane + Jenkins Crashlytics failed while migrating to FirebaseCrashlytics

Tags: jenkins, crashlytics, fastlane

As a developer and release manager I would like to set up automatic release of my beta iOS app and submit my Crashlytics to Firebase.

The it comes to Changing modules from Crashlytics/Fabric to FirebaseCrashlytics,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics

I find out the submission failed.

Here is my code :

```
crashlytics({
  crashlytics_path: '/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework',
  api_token: ENV['CRASHLYTICS_API_TOKEN'],
  build_secret: ENV['CRASHLYTICS_BUILD_SECRET'],
  ipa_path:$pathname + "/" + $filename + ".ipa",
  groups: "Real.co",
  notifications: "YES"
}

upload_symbols_to_crashlytics()
```